# Numerically equivalent effective divisors and semiampleness 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, positivity

Recall that a divisor $M$ on a variety $X$ is said to be semiample if $kM$ is base point free for a certain $k > 0$.

Being semiample is not a numerical property (take for example torsion and a non-torsion divisor of degree 0 on a curve, or for more sophisticated examples just look at Lazarsfeld - Positivity in Algebraic Geometry II - Ex. 10.3.3), therefore I was wondering:

It is possible to find a smooth projective variety $X$ and two effective divisors $E,D$ on $X$ such that $E \equiv D$, but $E$ is semiample while $H^0(X,kD)=\mathbb{C}$ for every $k$?

Answer (score 5):

Does Example 2.4 from [https://www.math.utah.edu/~hacon/commA.dvi](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ehacon/commA.dvi) answer your question?